# Windows Backup failed: Error 80070037

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup, usb-3

On Windows 7 Pro x64, the customer has a USB3 external Hard Drive that is 2TB, and two internal SATA drives that are 750GB each. They also have a USB controller, which the hard drive is plugged into. It fails at around 30% with "Error 80070037". No real details given, other than it can't find the device. I disabled power save mode on the device, and in the BIOS, but same error occurs. I formatted the drive and tried again, but no dice. I went through the backup settings, and told it to back up the entire system, and it starts, just to end again around 30% with the same error.

Currently, I am CHKDSKing the computer, and using the Western Digital DataLifeguard on the external drive. Will post back with results

**UPDATE** Chkdsk came back clean. Hard drive is fine. Waiting for WDDLG to finish on external, then I will try the USB port mentioned by @Moab

**UPDATE 2:** External hard drive checked out fine. Trying on USB 2 port now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have to do with usb 3.0 if you are using a 3.0 port, try backup using a 2.0 port, see if you get same error.

.

Comment: Starting to see USB 3.0 issues, makes me wonder if it is as good as they say.

Comment: Retagged to add USB 3