# Windows Backup Server Execution Failed 0x8008005

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I set up backup when I installed Windows 7 a long time ago and now I can't change its settings.

[image: server execution failed 0x8008005]

[Google gives me nothing.](http://www.google.com/search?q="windows%20backup"%20"server%20execution%20failed"%20"8008005")

I removed the USB (E:) to see [if it's a USB issue](https://superuser.com/questions/384464/windows-backup-failed-error-80070037) but still have the same error.

---

**Edit:** After much searching I've found that Microsoft knows about this and hasn't been able to solve it yet:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsbackup/thread/29bd3fc9-9538-4d82-9b13-96263c4f2f73
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/8669451c-772e-4bb4-91b0-9b089bf5c2cd

Comment: You should put your edit as an answer. And if no one else has come up with a solution in a couple of days you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Here are the registry locations for Windows backup, should be able to delete some of them to solve the issue...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb891959(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here are the registry locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb891959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows backup, should be able to delete some of them to solve the issue

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsBackup

Basically you are deleting 3 sub keys:

ScheduleParams
[image]

Security
[image]

Status
[image]

Which should leave it looking like this when done
[image]

[Tutorial here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/632-backup-user-system-files-reset-default-configuration.html)

Comment: [It reset the backup but didn't solve the issue, still getting the error.](http://i.imgur.com/uZ7mn.png)

Comment: Might be related to this COM error...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870655

Comment: Or you have a Security Program interfering with Backup, perform a clean boot, then try backup....http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-7/